# Office365 subscribing to calendar events

Tags: office365

I've been trying to get notifications from calendar with office 365, i managed to subscribe to events and I get a subscription Id however, whenever the notification url I provided gets called it doesn't get any POST or GET parameters with it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here is my subscription request params :

```
POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
   @odata.type:"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
   Resource: "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events",
   NotificationURL: "https://mywebsitehere/api/send/notificationClient",  
   ChangeType: "Created, Updated, Deleted"
}
```

Edit : The scope i use is https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite

Any idea what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll respond to myself :

It turns out that using $_POST doesn't work to get the data when its content-type is application/json so i used :

```
file_get_contents("php://input")
```

And problem solved after 2 days of searching...